# Explode JavaPairRDD objects

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a `JavaPairRDD<Dimension, Metrics>` , here `Dimension` & `Metrics` objects have bunch of members. Is there a way to convert this into `Dataset<Row>` with all the columns/members of both the objects. Or is there also a way to dump this `JavaPairRDD` to a file with the columns/members of both the objects separated by tab or comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [map()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html#map-org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function-) transformation to convert the JavaPairRDD to a JavaRDD representing all the members from Dimension and Metrics as comma separated string.

After this you can [save it as a Text file](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html#saveAsTextFile-java.lang.String-).

Logical steps to do this:

- Override toString() in Dimension and Metrics classes. You can possibly return a comma separated list of values as a string in there.

In your spark application -

```
Function<Tuple2<Dimension, Metrics>, String> f = tuple -> (tuple._1.toString() +"," + tuple._2.toString());
JavaRDD csvRdd = pairRDD.map(f);
csvRdd.saveAsTextFile("your file path")
```

- Amit